# Using HttpServletRequest in Spring Service Layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Environment :**

Spring  MVC 3

Angular JS

Tomcat 6

**Issue :**

We are migrating a legacy application from `struts2` to `spring MVC REST` with angular JS as UI.
This is a typical SPA.

The typical application flow is : Angular JS + Spring REST controller + Servicelayer

The business logic in struts2 actions is moved to service classes.

My question is - What is the correct way to make HttpServetRequest object available to Service classes in Spring ?

Two options available are :

1)Pass `HttpServletRequest` to Spring MVC controller method. Pass the same `HttpServetRequest` to Spring service layer.
  But this will result in `HttpServletRequest` being part of Service interface like -

```
public ProductDto getProductDetails(HttpServletRequest req,int productId)
```

Is this a correct way ? Can `HttpServletRequest` be part of Service interface ?

2)Use Spring provided API :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Please guide on this ?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to those mentioned options, you can introduce a class or another abstraction into your service layer, then populate it with the required parts of the `HttpServletRequest` and use that abstraction inside the *Service Layer*.

For example (Borrowed from Spring Data), Suppose you want to access to `page`, `size` and `sort` and user related query strings from the `HttpServletRequest`. Instead of passing the request to the service layer methods, you can also encapsulate those parameters into an abstraction, say, `Pageable` or `UserFilterCriteria`:

```
public interface Pageable {
    int page();
    int size();
    List<Sort> sorts();
}
```

Then instead of passing the `HttpServletRequest` to the service layer:

```
public interface UsersService {
    List<User> filterUsers(HttpServletRequest request);
}
```

You can pass those new abstractions:

```
public interface UsersService {
    List<User> filterUsers(UserFilterCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This way you can easily define abstractions in the same level of abstraction as your service layer.

Comment: If we want finer grain access to request object like getting/setting request/session attributes , then above approach would be dufficult

Answer (score 1):

You should rather not make HttpServletRequest/-Response be part of your service-layer, as HttpServletRequest/-Response are classes specific to your user interface/view technology.
Introducing them to your service layer will make your service layer depend on the technology used for the user interface, thus making it harder to change the UI/View technology later.